# Uploadify controller action and file retention issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using uploadify control in my ASP.NET MVC application to upload user selected files. I've placed the following code in the .js file:

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    'uploader': '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script': '/File/Upload',
    'cancelImg': '/Scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
    'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
    'auto': true,
    'multi': true,
    'sizeLimit': 1048576,
    'buttonText': 'Upload Files',

    'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
        alert(fileObj.name);       
    }
});
```

The controller has the following code:

```
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        private static string uploadedHTMLFile = string.Empty;

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
//do something
            }
}
```

I am having two problems:

1. The controller action is not being invoked.
2. The alert on OnComplete fires but the uploaded file just disappears from the screen after firing that event. How do I retain the list of files uploaded on the screen?

The `<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />` is defined in a .cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
            var filename = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            fileData.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        return Json(true);
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` View:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput1" id="fileInput1" data-upload-url="@Url.Action("upload")" data-uploadify-root="@Url.Content("~/scripts")" />
```

`Layout.cshtml` script references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/swfobject.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
```

`myscript.js`:

```
$(function () {
    var fileInput = $('#fileInput1');
    var uploadifyRoot = fileInput.data('uploadify-root');
    var uploadUrl = fileInput.data('upload-url');
    fileInput.uploadify({
        'uploader': uploadifyRoot + '/uploadify.swf',
        'script': uploadUrl,
        'cancelImg': uploadifyRoot + '/cancel.png',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
        'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.txt;*.zip',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'sizeLimit': 1048576,
        'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            alert(fileObj.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for controller action not being invoked is that the name of your `input type="file"` doesnot match with the parameter of the controller action.

Try like this in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file_upload)
{
}
```

you can either change the input type's name to `fileData` or else change the name of parameter to your action as stated above.

I'm not sure that my solution to second issue solves, but it may help you.

Try using `'removeCompleted': false` in your uploadify options so that even if the fileupload is successful, its stays on the page without disappearing.

Hope this helps.